# Regular Expression in visual basic6 for extracting mobile number

Tags: regex, vb6

I am using Regular Expression pattern for extracting Mobile number from a Link through **Visual basic6**. (Mobile number Format is ,`+923336241441` or `00923336241441` or `03336241441` or `0333 624 1441`). Regular Expression pattern that I am using is

`"(^((\+92)|(0092))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{4}-\d{7}$)"`

but failed to get any mobile number.Please check and guide me for correction.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
(^(?:(?:\+92)|(?:0092))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{4}-\d{7}$)
```

Try this.Yours was failing as `+` has to be escaped as it is a quatifier.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/8

Comment: Sorry , No Match result.

Comment: I am using Visual basic6.

Comment: @user2476866 works for me here https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/11  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818802

Comment: i also used pattern 
"\d{11,12}" but failed.

Comment: @user2476866 do you get any error are you applying it d correct wya

Comment: @user2476866. Can u please share d solution

Answer (score 0):

VBScript regular expressions do not support look-behinds of any type so try something like this

```
\+?(\d[ -]\d|\d)+
```

... for phone number matching. Basically anything that (optionally) starts with a + followed by numbers (optionally) separated by a single space or dash (but not ending in space or dash) is matched. So `0333 624 1441` is matched but `0333 624 - 1441` is not -- only `0333 624` is matched instead.